# AWK: substitute function sub() didn't work

Tags: awk

I need to search for a mult-line text in a file 'cfg_file' and replace that text with another text.
The text to search for is in 'cfg_name' and the replacement text is in 'cfg_value'.
I'm using ubuntu m/c.

cfg_file:

```
rem01=("LOG_CHAN01_REM_IP" transport("tcp") port( LOG_CHAN01_REM_PORT ) );
rem02=("LOG_CHAN02_REM_IP" transport("tcp") port( LOG_CHAN02_REM_PORT ) );
```

cfg_name:

```
LOG_CHAN01_REM_IP
LOG_CHAN01_REM_PORT
LOG_CHAN02_REM_IP
LOG_CHAN02_REM_PORT
```

cfg_value:

```
10.123.122.52
50001
10.15.19.51
50002
```

I used the below script (got it from some earlier queries in the web), but didn't work as expected. Any idea???

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="" } 
FILENAME==ARGV[1] { s=$0 }
FILENAME==ARGV[2] { r=$0 }
FILENAME==ARGV[3] { sub(s,r); print }
END { print NR, "Students Records are processed." }
' ./cfg_name ./cfg_value ./cfg_file > ./outfile
```

Comment: [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html) might be a better choice than awk for this.

Answer (score 3):

#### AWK Solution

There are better tools to do this. However, if you insist in awk:

```
FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
    name[FNR] = $0
}

FILENAME == ARGV[2] {
    value[name[FNR]] = $0
}

FILENAME == ARGV[3] && FNR <= 20000 {
    for (n in value) {
        gsub(n, value[n]);
    }
    print
}
```

#### M4 Solution

As Catcall suggested, we can use m4:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script's arguments: cfg_name cfg_value cfg_file
{
    paste $1 $2 | while read name value
    do
        echo "define(\`${name}', \`${value}')"
    done
    cat $3
} | m4
echo "$(wc -l $3) Students Records are processed."
```

Comment: I need to perform this on a file having 5000 lines. Will it be possible to perform this operation without loop to reduce the time to generate the output file?

Comment: Is there a problem with my solution?

Comment: How long does it take to process 5000 lines of text?

Comment: It works great, thanks for that. At the moment it takes about 15sec to perform this activity. I'm using this in embedded system, where I get only 5sec to 8sec to do this. Will it be possible to limit this search and replace for first 2000 lines in 'cfg_file' file?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That works great. Thank you once again for your time.

Comment: Thanks, @HaiVu. I was on a Windows netbook without Cygwin installed when I made that comment about m4. By the time I got home, I'd forgotten about it.

Answer (score 2):

Another awk version, with just one loop to read the variables:

```
BEGIN {
  # Read all variables in VAR_TABLE
  while( ( getline VAR < cfg_name ) > 0 ) {
    if ( ( getline VALUE < cfg_value ) > 0 ) {
      VAR_TABLE[ VAR ] = VALUE
    } else {
      print "ERROR: no value for " VAR > "/dev/stderr"
    }
  }
}

{
   # Convert all lines
   for ( VAR in VAR_TABLE ) { gsub( VAR, VAR_TABLE[ VAR ] ) }
   print
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the solution have to be in AWK?

Here is some python code that would get you started... Save this to a file "replace.py" and then just run it. I plugged in the file names you specified in your question.

```
substitution_dict = {}
name_file = open("cfg_name","r")
value_file = open("cfg_value","r")
for line in name_file.readlines():
    name = line.strip()
    value = value_file.readline().strip()
    substitution_dict[name]=value

for line in open("cfg_file","r").readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    for name in substitution_dict.keys():
        line = line.replace(name, substitution_dict[name])
    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way is read first the 2 files (name and value) and then apply the replacement to the cfg_file.

The AWK code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    file = ARGV[1];
    name = ARGV[2];
    value = ARGV[3];
    ARGC = 2;
    i = 1;
    while ( (getline < name) > 0 ) {
        names[i] = $1;
        i++;
    }
    i = 1;
    while ( (getline < value) > 0 ) {
        values[i] = $1;
        i++;
    }
}
{
    for ( i in names ) {
        sub( names[i], values[i], $0 );
    }
    print $0;
}
END {
    print NR" Students Records are processed.";
}
```

I saved the code to `merge.awk` that you can invoke this way:

```
awk -f merge.awk ./cfg_file ./cfg_name ./cfg_value
```

And the output is:

```
rem01=("10.123.122.52" transport("tcp") port( 50001 ) );
rem02=("10.15.19.51" transport("tcp") port( 50002 ) );
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the solution. I need to perform this on a file having 5000 lines. Will it be possible to perform this operation without loop to reduce the time?